# (emacs) kbd の引数になるような文字列を、そのまま入力するには？

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs の設定中には、 kbd の引数になるような、"C-c x h" のような文字列を何回か触ることになるのですが、この文字列を、キーを直接「C-c」、「x」、「h」と叩くことによって、入力したいのですが、これは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下を実行すれば可能ですが、

```
(key-description (read-key-sequence nil))
```

これでは分かりづらいかも知れませんので、

```
(key-description (read-key-sequence "input> "))
```

などとしてみて下さい。`describe-function` で `read-key-sequence` を調べてもらえばお分かりいただけるかと思いますが、`"input> "` は入力プロンプト(ミニバッファに表示)になります。
なお、「**kbd の引数になるような**」との事ですので、`\C-cx` がプレフィックスキーとして定義されている事が前提となります。そうでない場合には、`C-c x` とだけ表示されることになります。